# Most Efficient Way to "Slurp" All of STDIN Into a String

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, io, stdin

I'm writing an email parser for python 2.7 that will be invoked via sendmail using an alias, parsed using the email module and then processed and stored into an oracle database:

From /etc/aliases:

myalias: | /my/python/script.py

I'm having trouble "slurping" all of stdin into a string object that I can use with the email module:

```
import email

# Slurp stdin and store into message
message =

msg = email.message_from_string(message)

# Do something with it
print msg['Subject']
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this? I've tried stdin.readlines() but it ends up as a list.

Thx for any help. (Sorry if this is noobish... I'm a perl convert and been forced to standardize my tools using python and this is only my second script. Well not really "forced", I've been wanting to do this for some time but not under the gun of a deadline like now)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`sys.stdin.readlines()` returns a list of lines. If what you want is one long (multi-line) string, use `sys.stdin.read()`.

Comment: If you want to slurp instead of sip, keep reading stdin until it returns 0 bytes, otherwise you'll have problems with larger messages.

Comment: @tdelaney why is that? do you have a source I can read up on? I just tested that with `cat ~/bash_history | test.py` which's a large file, the length of the second sys.stdin.read was always 0. with Python version 3.7.3.

Comment: Python is not C. `pydoc sys.stdin.read` says: "If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached."